# call self object fail in ajax success

Tags: javascript, ajax

I define a class like this:

```
var LoadingPolecy={
    initialize:function(){
        return function(){
               this.initialize.apply(this,arguments);
        }    
    }
}
var AjaxLoadingPolecy= LoadingPolecy.initialize();
AjaxLoadingPolecy.prototype={
    initialize:function(name){
        this.name=name;
    },
    AjaxStartPolecy : function(){
        ...
    },
    AjaxStopPolecy : function(){
        ...   
    },
    SetName : function(name){
        ...
    }
}
var TempLoadingPolecy=LoadingPolecy.initialize();
TempLoadingPolecy.prototype={
    initialize:function(displayArea,source,data){
        this.loadingMsgPolecy = new AjaxLoadingPolecy();
                ...
        },
        StartLoadingTempPolecy : function(callback){
        this.loadingMsgPolecy.SetName('view');
        this.loadingMsgPolecy.AjaxStartPolecy();
        var a = $.ajax({
          ...
          success:function(html){
              callback(html);
          }
        });
    },
        EndLoadingTempPolecy : function(html){
           //Cannot call method 'AjaxStopPolecy' of undefined error
        this.loadingMsgPolecy.AjaxStopPolecy();
                ....
        }
}
```

I seems the object in this has been changed, how can I call/ use the variables that I defined in initialize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ajax success callback (and the same for most other callbacks) does not give you the same `this`.  But, you can save the previous copy of `this` into another variable and access it that way:

I don't understand which part of your code you are asking about, but here's a simple example that you can adapt from:

```
initialize:function(displayArea,source,data){
    StartLoadingTempPolecy : function(callback) {
        this.loadingMsgPolecy.SetName('view');
        this.loadingMsgPolecy.AjaxStartPolecy();
        // save copy of `this` for future use in the success handler
        var self = this;
        var a = $.ajax({
          ...
          success:function(html) {
              // you can use the variable `self` here to access the previous this ptr
              callback(html);
          }
    });
},
```